# Weird behaviour of loops in python

Tags: python, loops

So I was trying to do some basic stuff list stuff in a different way, and I came across weird behaviour in this code. I'm not sure if its a compiler/machine dependent result and I can't even google this because I'm just so lost.

Edit: In response to some people, I get that my code is incorrect in its semantics, but the behaviour of the code after the mistake is what I wanted to understand. Thanks for the corrections though!

Here is the code:

```
import random

L = (int(input("For List 1, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 5)))
L1 = (int(input("For List 2, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 6)))

common = []

for i in L:
  if i in L1:
    common.append(i)

print(common)
```

From my limited understanding, line 3 and 5 should have just resulted in L and L1 having the last entered integer stored in them, but when I execute the program it just flits between line 3 and 5. Furthermore, if I try to print L and L1 it just prints its object type (genexpr) and location in memory, before the prompts for inputs. Why is the code behaving that way?

Comment: Can you provide a static input for `L` and `L1` to have a reproducible code?

Comment: Here loop works in a predictible way. But `L` and `L1` generators are weird. What you want to do in these lines? Or it  must be not generator but just list?

Comment: Yeah @IhorKonovalenko I know the code is technically incorrect. I didn't say that because I thought it'd come off weird. I just wanted to initialize 2 lists, and in one of my incorrect code iterations I made this, and it takes inputs for list 1 and then list 2 interchangeably in a random fashion.

Comment: @mozway I'm sorry I don't know what a static input is... Do you mean a set of inputs that recreate the weird behaviour? For me it happened on any input for the program. The code would kind of "take turns" in taking an input for list 1 and list 2, which confused me and prompted me to putting up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected bahavior is caused by the generator expressions, which are evaluated lazily.

This means that the values for `L` and `L1` will be generated as needed, one value at a time.

The loop

```
for i in L:
```

can be executed by creating a single value for `L` in each iteration.
*This is why you will see one prompt `"For List 1, enter a number: "` for each iteration of the outer `for` loop!*

However, the `if` statement

```
if i in L1:
```

requires values to be created for `L1` until `i` is found or until there are no more values to generate for `L1`.

Example:

```
>>> L1 = (x for x in (1, 2, 3, 4))
>>> 3 in L1
True
>>> next(L1)
4
>>> next(L1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
StopIteration
```

To avoid the lazy evaluation, use lists instead of generator expressions, i.e.

```
L = [int(input("For List 1, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 5))]
L1 = [int(input("For List 2, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 6))]
```

Comment: So the generator makes a new value for L at every prompt, I got that much. But what makes it break the sequence in the code? When I execute the program, it would interchangeably ask an input for L and L1 (I can differentiate with list 1 and list 2 in prompts) after any input. Also thanks for a nice answer!

Comment: @Sid I misread you original code as nested `for` loops instead of `for/if`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to use a list comprehension with square brackets instead of curved brackets.

```
import random

L = [int(input("For List 1, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 5))]
L1 = [int(input("For List 2, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 6))]
common = []

for i in L:
  if i in L1:
    common.append(i)

print(common)
```

If you instead want to do a tuple comprehension, you could do it as follows:

```
import random

L = tuple(int(input("For List 1, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 5)))
L1 = tuple(int(input("For List 2, enter a number: ")) for i in range(random.randint(2, 6)))
common = []

for i in L:
  if i in L1:
    common.append(i)

print(common)
```

Comment: I think I should have been clearer on the fact that I managed to get it working properly afterwards, but I was just curious as to what the poorly defined behaviour was being caused by. Let me just edit my question for clarity's sake.